# Add new column in raster attribute table

Tags: raster, r

I would like to add a new column in a raster attribute table and populate it with values based on another column using `if statement`, the new column should have letters such as A, B, C and D. How do I do that in R?

Comment: Is this the raster package with the ratify function? What have you tried?

Comment: @mdsumner I used the ratify function but could not extract the attribute I created. I ended up coding the values based on another column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a modified example from the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/raster.pdf):

```
# create raster
r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
r[] = 1
r[51:100] = 2
r[3:6, 1:5] = 3
r[,1:2] = 4

# access raster attribute table
r <- ratify(r)
rat <- levels(r)[[1]]

# assign new letters attributes (A-D)
rat$letters <- LETTERS[1:4]
levels(r) <- rat

# get assigned letters for all raster cells
factorValues(r, extract(r, c(1:100)))$letters
```